# How can roll back when saving data to cloud-firestore if there is an error?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save data to four document in firestore. But I want to cancel all saving if in one of docs has error. I dont know it is possible with async-await. I share with you giveOrder function and button function that I call the giveOrder function in it. Finally ss is I got the error. May you help me

```
public func giveOrder(description: String, total: String, orderModel: [ChosenProduct]) async throws -> Bool {
    let dealerID = orderModel[0].dealerID
    let orderID = UUID().uuidString
    getAccountID { email, customerID in
        let orderInfo: [String : Any] = ["Date": Date.now,
                                         "Dealer ID": dealerID,
                                         "Customer ID": customerID,
                                         "Statu": "Preparing",
                                         "Order ID": orderID,
                                         "Description": description,
                                         "Total Cost": total]
        self.reference = self.database.document("Orders/\(customerID)/\(orderID)/Order Info")
        self.thirdReference = self.database.document("Orders/\(dealerID)/\(orderID)/Order Info")
        
        Task {
            try await self.reference.setData(orderInfo, merge: true)
            for product in orderModel {
                let orderPost: [String : Any] = ["Name" : product.name,
                                                 "Store Name" : product.storeName,
                                                 "Unit": product.unit,
                                                 "Unit Type": product.unitType,
                                                 "Price": product.price,
                                                 "Price Type": product.priceType,
                                                 "Product ID": product.id,
                                                 "Dealer ID": product.dealerID]
                self.secondReference = self.database.document("Orders/\(customerID)/\(orderID)/\(product.id)")
                try await self.secondReference.setData(orderPost, merge: true)
            }
            
            
            
            try await self.thirdReference.setData(orderInfo, merge: true)
            for product in orderModel {
                let orderPost: [String : Any] = ["Name" : product.name,
                                                 "Store Name" : product.storeName,
                                                 "Unit": product.unit,
                                                 "Unit Type": product.unitType,
                                                 "Price": product.price,
                                                 "Price Type": product.priceType,
                                                 "Product ID": product.id,
                                                 "Customer ID": customerID]
                self.fourthReference = self.database.document("Orders/\(dealerID)/\(orderID)/\(product.id)")
                try await self.fourthReference.setData(orderPost, merge: true)
            }
        }
        
    }
    return true
}
```

This is button function:

```
@objc func tappedBuyButton() async {
        let comment = commentText.text ?? "No comments"
        let total = totalLabel.text
        let ordered = NewOrderVC.chosenProducts
        do {
            let success = try await DatabaseManager.shared.giveOrder(description: comment, total: total!, orderModel: ordered)
            if success {
                NewOrderVC.chosenProducts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: "Could not order. Please try again!")
            }
        } catch {
            self.makeAlert(title: "Error", message: "Could not order. Please try again!")
        }
    }
```

And this is the thread I got:
[error: memory read failed for 0x2b88f7db5e00

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2b88f7db5e90)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSS0e.png)

Comment: First, the bad access and the cancelation are two completely separate questions. Please, one question per post. Second, I’m not sure we have enough to diagnose the bad access issue. All I can suggest is turning on TSAN (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/) and see what it reports. But we can’t see what `getAccountId` is doing, so we can’t possibly comment on what races might be underway. But we want [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), regardless, not more code.

Comment: Third, I’d discourage the use of a `Task` inside a completion handler closure. Either use Swift concurrency or don’t. It’s weird to be initiating a `Task` from within an unknown context. Fourth, your throwing task will exit as soon as one throws and error and it will not proceed to run the other lines, so it should stop when one fails. So, I’m not sure what you mean by “How can cancel the all function if one of the functions return error?”

Comment: There are four firestore reference in Task. I want to cancel to save data in these reference if there is an error in one of them. I don't know using async-await sensible. I'm new on coding. So sorry for bad explanation. Thank you for response. I'll check TSAN.

Comment: I want to save four different data in firestore database. Code is running respectively. For example, first and second data saved to firestore database. After that, while third one save in there, internet connection lost and got error. In this case I don't want to save any data to any reference. I tried this with using async-await. I want to know is this right usage?

Comment: Yes, I want to roll back.

Comment: Ok, I'll search for firebase. Thank you for patient.

Comment: Or, edit the question to excise the unrelated crash and just more clearly articulate the desired "roll back" behavior. Whatever works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say it dies after successfully saving steps 1 and 2, but before it finishes step 3. Are you saying that you want it to gracefully stop, not saving steps 3 and 4? Or are you saying that you want it to also roll back 1 and 2, as well?

If you want it to roll back and are using Cloud FireStore, you might consider using transactions and [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> **Batched writes**
>
> If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you
> can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains
> any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of
> writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents. The
> following example shows how to build and commit a write batch:
>
> ```swift
> // Get new write batch 
> let batch = db.batch()
>
> // Set the value of 'NYC' 
> let nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC") 
> batch.setData([:], forDocument: nycRef)
>
> // Update the population of 'SF'
> let sfRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF") 
> batch.updateData(["population": 1000000 ], forDocument: sfRef)
>
> // Delete the city 'LA' 
> let laRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA") 
> batch.deleteDocument(laRef)
>
> // Commit the batch
> batch.commit() { err in
>     if let err = err {
>         print("Error writing batch \(err)")
>     } else {
>         print("Batch write succeeded.")
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage.
>
> Like transactions, batched writes are atomic. Unlike transactions, batched writes do not need to ensure that read documents remain un-modified which leads to fewer failure cases. They are not subject to retries or to failures from too many retries. Batched writes execute even when the user's device is offline.